# what is data acquisition layer and Structure in spring mvc

Tags: spring-mvc, data-acquisition

i have a webapp to receive data from devices, 
and i have a requirements from my customer with following specs-
that Data Acquisition Layer should work on open source MQ based delivery mechanism.
a) Data acquisition layer must be platform independent and able to run on Linux or windows .etc.operating system and should be developed in java Gdk6).

I don't know what is data acquisition layer

do i need to implement it on another separate project 
my application is developed in spring MVC

please help me to understand the structure how should i implement it

Answer (score 1):

"what so ever no assumptions" is the classical piece of advice given by my boss .so instead assume things you can better ask him for a requirement document which clearly explains what he wants rather than assume something .later it may be difficult for you.

Now coming to your question .

Data acquisition layer:A component that uses  database or file system to store the data  .that is it is a storage kind of thing where you put all the data with help of application.since in your case platform independent it can be build with java .

> do i need to implement it on another separate project my application is
>   developed in spring MVC ?

No Absolutely not you can build as a module in same project .spring is one the best choice for your application you either try rabbitmq or activemq for message queue .
spring offers good integration with rabbitmq or activemq

you send the message to the queue from the queue it will get inserted in to the db or you can write it to a file system

[spring rabbit mq example getting started guide with spring boot](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-rabbitmq/)

[spring rabbit mq example](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/2.0.0.M1/reference/html/_introduction.html#_rabbittemplate_changes)

Comment: thanks for your reply i also thinks that i need some more detail what they want. thank u